# ngOnInit not called when same component is loaded with different data

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an angular 2 app, and I use router to navigate between views, like everyone else. Here is how my path for a particular component look like:

```
{
    path: 'home/view1/:viewID',
    component: ViewComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'pane/:paneId/section/:sectionId', component: SectionEditComponent },
        { path: '**', component: ViewEditComponent }
    ]
},
```

Now, I have two buttons on the ViewComponent, to load SectionEditComponent for section1 and section2.

Path1: pane/1/section/1
Path2: pane/1/section/2

ViewComponent template:

```
   <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: white; height: 100%">
       <button (click)="loadPath(1)">Path1</button>
       <button (click)="loadPath(2)">Path2</button>
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
```

Now, when I navigate from Path1->Path2 or Path2->Path1 within same ViewComponent, the ngOnInit() is not called, thus not loading the new path, even though the url actually change according to the new section ID.

Is this known or expected behavior? Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inject the route and subscribe to parameters change

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
  route.params.forEach(params => {
    myInit(params['paramId']);
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this good practice? Shouldn't you `subscribe` to the params or will that give the same issues? Do you know why `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` doesn't seem to solve it also?

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to add that if you're using a route resolver to get data before the component loads then you can put the following code in your component's ngOnInit method:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
         initData(data['mydata']);
    });
}

initData(data){
    // process new data
}
```

Now whenever your resolver updates the route's resolved data your component's model will get updated and display the new data.

Answer (score 3):

For the same instance of the component, `ngOnInit()` gets called once only.

Comment: Thanks, so how to achieve a reload? (or if there is any other method that's called every time)

Comment: But what exactly do you  want to achieve ?

Comment: Actually I have an component initialization logic that's based on route params. @Günter Zöchbauer's answer is exactly what I was looking for (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39962929/6950218)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with ngOnInit not being called on route change.
I moved the code  to **ngAfterViewInit()** and it worked.

Comment: I got `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.` when doing this. Also, it didn't trigger twice, when reusing the component, so I'm not sure if it even works.

Comment: @TetraDev this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked