# How to get ordered indices inside two ngFor's?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my demo code where i explain my goal in comments:

**product.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items1">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items2">     
      <input type="text" value="{{data[getNumber()]}}"> //I want to get data[0] till data[6]
  </div>
</div>
```

**product.component.ts**

```
export class ProductComponent{

  itens1=["A","B","C","D"];
  itens2=["X","Y","Z"];
  data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

  number=0;

  getNumber(){
    return this.number++;
  }

}
```

These are the errors i get:

[image]

I hope to have explained my problem well.

Comment: Well, your question is a little bit confuse. What's data? A primitive array? Why do you need that function `getNumber()`? I don't know what do you want but you can try the following: `<div ngFor="let item of items2; let i = index;">
  <input type="text" [value]="data[i]">`.

Comment: @developer033 Yes `data` is a primitive array. I have tryed your suggestion but i dont want to increment the index of `data` just when the second `ngFor` finishes. I want to increment it on each iteraction

Comment: What do you mean by **"but i dont want to increment the index of data just when the second ngFor finishes"**?

Comment: My bad. I mean i want to keep  incrementing even when the second `ngFor` finishes. eg. `itens1=['A','B']; itens2=['X','Y']; data=[1,2,3,4];` i want `<input>` to have `data[0]` untill `data[3]`

Comment: See my answer. Also, you have to write `*ngFor`, not just `ngFor`, but I suspect that was just a typo.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Yes, it's a typo. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time `getNumber()` is called, it returns a different value than before.

Every time Angular2 evaluates what to set `value` to during change detection, it has changed, it never settles. Angular2 regards this as an error. [See this answer for a more complete explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364881/46194).

The following code works the way you intend. Note that getNumber is now idempotent, it gives the same result for the same input. The input is gotten from the loops using the syntax `let i = index`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'product',
    template: `
<div *ngFor="let item of items1; let i = index">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items2; let j = index">
      <input type="text" value="{{data[getNumber(i, j)]}}">
  </div>
</div>`
})
export class ProductComponent {
    items1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
    items2 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'];
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    getNumber(i: number, j: number) {
        return i * this.items2.length + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: One upvote for the answer but could it be more dynamic? I mean if `itens1.length` is 4 and `itens2.length` is 3 and `data` has more values, the `getNumber()` function will not return ordered indices. Check my edits on the question for details.

Comment: I've updated with larger arrays and a more generic `getNumber`. Note that the as the example stands it works but it runs out of `data` values to display, since you would need `itens1.length * itens2.length` values in `data`.