# Angular 2 - Expression has changed after it was checked when passing directive

Tags: angular

What's wrong here?

template:

```
<drr-person (isMinorEmittor)="setPersonIsMinor($event)" [group]="requesterForm" [required]="true" ></drr-person>
```

ts:

```
ngOnInit() {

    if (!this.required)
        this.personForm.addControl("nationalnumber", this.fb.control("", [Validators.minLength(11)]));
    else
        this.personForm.addControl("nationalnumber", this.fb.control("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(11)]));

}
```

Throws:

EXCEPTION: Error in ... caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression \_\_\_ has changed after it was checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)