# Why does Angular 2 not detect change?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

I am having a similar code and error as [Expression ___ has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked) where I am changing a variable value in `ngAfterViewInit()`.

One of the answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243106/1460595 suggests to manually trigger change detection by calling `detectChanges()` method of `ChangeDetectorRef`, which works.

But why do we have to handle change manually when Angular 2 should be handling the change? 
Is there some relationship between lifecycle hooks and change detection?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by a 2nd change detection run after each regular one done by Angular in development mode, to check if the model has stabilized, otherwise this is an indication for a probable bug.

In your case the problem is, that the lifecycle callback `ngAfterViewInit` is called by the first change detection run. If it updates the modelm the 2nd change detection run throws. With a manual change detection run after the update, Angular gets its remembered values updates and the 2nd CD run won't notify a change.

Comment: so is there a lifecycle hook that tells us change detection run is complete?

Comment: No, just run `detectChanges()`. I haven't seen a better method yet. You could try `ngAfterContentInit`, don't remember if you get the error as well.