# Angular dynamic component loading - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I need to create instances of multiple components dynamically on the run.

I found several examples on the internet, including StackOverflow and angular.io page itself.

But always receiving exception ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when I'm assigning a value to the component model.

Even the dedicated example for this functionality throws the same exception:
[Angular.io article](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html)
[Plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-dynamic-component-loader/ts/eplnkr.html)

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'Bombasto'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?

Should I just ignore this or it can/should be fixed?

Comment: this is newbie error :). don't change the state of the component manually after it was already *checked*. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/34364880/573032

Comment: thx guys, will have a look on it. Rusev solved the actual bug

Comment: [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you are altering component state in `ngAfterViewInit`. See the [issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15464) discussing the behavior.

In your case you can move the initial creating in `ngOnInit`.

```typescript
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
    this.getAds();
 }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/vAbkBIqrhpuuWadO4zGD?p=preview

Comment: Many thanks, this solved issue. Didn't expected bug directly in Angular docs on such a key functionality

Comment: Actually it is not a bug, but a intended behavior - very annoying one :).

Comment: Currently the official example about dynamic component loading contains that error https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-component-loader/eplnkr.html - this solution applies to that as  well

Comment: This article shows another method using async update with a microtask: https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/

Answer (score 5):

In the more general case

use

```typescript
this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
```

at the end of the method that did update to late the component state,

... not forgetting to add

```typescript
private _changeDetectionRef : ChangeDetectorRef
```

as parameter of the constructor of the Component owning your method.

See discution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005)