# Expression has changed error in KendoUI for angular 2 dropdown

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am currently developing application on Angular 2(4) with KendoUI components for Angular.

Now I am trying to implement simple form with DropdownList. Data for that dropdown is loading from remote api. The problem is that when dropdown is opened i receive a very confusing error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '590px'.
```

I am not expirienced in Angular so any help will be appreciated.

Markup :

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist formControlName="parentCompanyId" class="form-control" [valuePrimitive]="true" [data]="parentCompanys"
                            textField="name" valueField="id" ></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

component(simplified):

```
export class EmployerComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    public Employer: Employer = new Employer();

    public employerForm: FormGroup;

    public parentCompanys: Array<any> = [];

    constructor(private employersService: EmployersService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.employerForm = new FormGroup({
            parentCompanyId: new FormControl(this.Employer.ParentCompanyId, [
                Validators.required
            ])
        });

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.employersService.getCompanies().subscribe(response => {
            this.parentCompanys = response.data;
        });

    }
}
```

UPD: 04.07.2017

I spent some time trying to solve this issue with different solutions from question mentioned in comment ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)) without any success.

But today i have updated my kendo-ui packages and it seems that error is gone. I am not sure but looks like it was a bug in kendo-ui component.

the links which i belive related to this issue

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/687

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/712

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression \_\_\_ has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

Comment: Read the duplicate :)  This happens in dev mode, you can manually trigger change detection to overcome this problem.