# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Angular v4.3.0

Tags: angular

I have an error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.
Plunk: `http://plnkr.co/edit/XKfHDAzuhjAhVvbQOpsW?p=preview`

I find a explanation:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked
```

But I did't know how I should make correct fix for this problem without an setTimeout in ngAfterViewInit.

The problem is with this.message variable. + same problem with ngAfterViewChecked. There is an fix without BehaviorSubject?

Comment: Use ChangeDetectorRef like in one of the answers. http://plnkr.co/edit/oGWe6zuOHyZVB38M1X3a?p=preview

Comment: Please add the essential parts of the code to the question directly instead of just linking to external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `message` property of the `Child` component in the template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  template: `
    <div>{{ message }}<input></div>`,
})
export class Child
```

Angular runs change detection (check) for the `child` component and updates the DOM. Then it remembers the value it used to update the DOM. This value will be used during verification step to check that bindings have not changed. The problem is that you're changing that value in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook and this hook is triggered after the `child` component is checked. So the when Angular runs verification for the component it notices that the value is different. So it throws the error. Angular requires additional change detection run between the check and the verification phase.

If you really need to update the value in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook, 
use it asynchronously or run change detection for the child component. Both are bad. Consider changing the application design.

See [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) article that explains the causes for the error and possible fixes in great details.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `this.ref.detectChanges();` on all `ngAfterViewChecked` types func.