# Angular's `cdRef.detectChanges` doesn't prevent checked exception?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a situation where I have an *inner* component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Name   =  {{name}}!</h1> `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Output() ev: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ev.emit("new name");
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Where in the parent component :

```
 <hello name="{{ name }}" (ev)="changeName($event)"></hello>


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  changeName(e) {
    this.name = e;
    console.log(e)
  }

}
```

*So basically , when the inner component loads , it emits an event which in turn received by parent and re-set the value of its inner component.*

But  this code ( and I do know why) - yields an exception :

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'Angular 5'. Current
>   value: 'new name'.

But according to [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243106/859154) in SO:

This line : `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` **should have** caused a new detection and prevent the exception.

*I already know that `setTimeout()...` does solve it in a hacky way.*

**Question:**

Why doesn't `detectChanges` prevent the exception ?

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ertdq1?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Does an `Output` triggers change dtetection ?

Comment: @trichetriche Who said that ? `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` should trigger

Comment: this was a question ... But from what I understand, if it doesn't trigger a change detection, then it means it changes the value of a variable after it has been checked, thus making the error, doesn't it  ?

Comment: @trichetriche Yeah I don't know what i'm missing here. Basically it's a sub component that yields an event to tell her parent to set a new value in it.

Comment: Well, as I said just before, `if it doesn't trigger a change detection, then it means it changes the value of a variable after it has been checked, thus making the error`. Maybe that is why a timeout is working while an emit isn't

Comment: @trichetriche so in which ng-event you'd emit ? ngoninit is one of the first

Comment: I would use a timeout I guess

Comment: Do you know where the error comes from? ` It comes from parent component `<hello name="{{ name }}"`

Comment: @yurzui yes : when I set a new name : https://i.imgur.com/pyF3Nxr.jpg

Comment: You call changeDetection in child but there nothing has changed after was checked

Comment: @yurzui so what should I in case where a child emits event which causes the parent to change input value of his son ?

Comment: If you call detectChanges in parent component then you will run into `maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @yurzui Right. I tried application.tick() in parent and got recursion error.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ik4jkd?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui thank you very much.  So from my understanding , `detectchanges` only trigger change detection from this point , downwards. right ? that's why you called it from above ?

Comment: Yep, it goes from current view down through all child views. It can omit detect changes for views that have OnPush strategy. setTimeout runs macrotask after that app.tick will be called. If you call app.tick directly during current execution of tick then you will get exception about recursive calling.