# Angular: ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

What's wrong?
Getting the following error in console:

```
AboutComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: 
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was 
checked. Previous value: 'null: undefined'. Current value: 'null: [object Object]'.
```

```typescript
import { AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

export class Test {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  template: `
    {{asd}}
  `
})
export class AboutComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  asd: Test;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.asd = new Test();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a discussion about this here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14748

Comment: This is a good reference as well: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: Follow this...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked

Answer (score 38):

You can also force change detection after you make a change within ngAfterViewInit() as such:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

export class Test {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  template: `
    {{asd}}
  `
})
export class AboutComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  asd: Test;

  constructor(
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef   
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.asd = new Test();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

> Some Lifecycle hooks are called before the rendering part when Angular processes
> bindings and some are called after that

Ref: https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10

The error is due to the Angular call this  ngAfterViewInit method once all the binding processed. To get rid this error you can do the following

Move your code inside ngOnInit lifecycle hook

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data = new Test()
}
```

Or

Wrap your code inside setTimeout()

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>this.data = new Test(),0)
  }
```

***Great Article about the same issue:*** https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Comment: This answer guided me to solution in my App where @ViewChild('form', { static: false}) form: FormGroup<any, any>; had to be changed to {static: true}. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcom @Mirosław

Answer (score 3):

In my case, what helped was addin:

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me is:

```
ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  },
```

Your component must implement: `AfterContentChecked` and `ChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: Any difference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71196059/5468463?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while working on Loader subscription with MatSpinner

I fixed it by adding

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loading$ = this.loader.loading$;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

This piece of code has to be added to the TS file in which you have defined the template., not in any submodule or files below a module
if the Template refered is **app.component.html** where we have a spinnner, the TS file where it should be present is **app.component.ts**