# Cannot Bind Dynamic Data in Component Angular 8

Tags: json, angular, jquery-select2, angular8

Error when component loading dynamic

> DynamicBuilderComponent.ngfactory.js:198 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-pristine: true'. Current value: 'ng-pristine: false'.

Problem

```
    after binding json in select2data to select2 component Angular throw exception.
```

component code

```
           @Component({
              changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
              selector: 'select2',
```

Imported changeDetection  in component.

```
              template: `
                  <div [formGroup]="form">

                    <ng-container>
                        <ng-select2
                          [data]="select2data"
                          [options]="options"
                          [width]="500"

                          [formControlName]="field.code"
                          (keyup)="changed($event.target.value)">
                        </ng-select2>
                    </ng-container>

                  </div>`
            })
```

select2 component class

```
            export class Select2Component implements OnInit {
              @Input() field: any = {};
              @Input() form: FormGroup;
              public exampleData: Array<Select2OptionData>;
              public options: Options;
              public value: string[];
              select2data: any;
              public selected: string;

              constructor(public cl: Services,private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
                this.options = {
                  width: '258',
                  multiple: true,
                  tags: false
                };
              }
```

Problem Area After Binding subscribe data in ng select2 component

```
              changed(search: any) {

               //call service pass search text to service
                return this.cl.searchFunc(search).subscribe(
                  res1 => 
                          this.select2data = res1.data;
                              this.cd.markForCheck(); // marks path
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  error => {
                    console.log('error  = ', error);
                  });
              }

            }
```

i tried to print  this.select2data in console.log its return me json.

Vendor.js

```
            function expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError(context, oldValue, currValue, isFirstCheck) {
                var msg = "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '" + oldValue + "'. Current value: '" + currValue + "'.";
                if (isFirstCheck) {
                    msg +=
                        " It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked." +
                            " Has it been created in a change detection hook ?";
                }
                return viewDebugError(msg, context);
            }
```

Great Article

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Reference

[Expression ___ has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

- any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you put your component `select2` inside another component which contains a form which you then pass to `select2` for create another `<form>` tag, is that correct? I mean do you have something like that?

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <!-- Some code -->
    <select2 [field]="something" [form]="form"></select2>
</form>
```

If so, then your `select2` component SHOULD NOT contain re-declaration of form, it should not contain anything related to forms at all. It should be a form control. Please read [a post](https://netbasal.com/angular-custom-form-controls-made-easy-4f963341c8e2) by Netanel Basal on how to create custom form controls. You will need to create `ControlValueAccessor` for your `select2` and wire it up to Angular forms through a custom provider.

The issue you're facing is that since you include `form` object twice in the DOM data changes are propagated twice as well and you run into issues. There should be only one reference to a specific instance of `FormGroup` in your templates.

Comment: As I said, you need to convert your `select2` component into a custom form control and you should not use `form` references at all.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked

```
         @Component({
          changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
          selector: 'select2',
          export class Select2Component implements OnInit {
            constructor(public cl: Services,private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
            this.options = {
              width: '258',
              multiple: true,
              tags: false
            };
          }
```

Binding function

```
 changed(search: any) {

           //call service pass search text to service
            return this.cl.searchFunc(search).subscribe(
              res1 => 
                      this.select2data = res1.data;
                      this.cd.markForCheck(); // marks path
                     this.cd.detectChanges();
                  }
                }
              },
              error => {
                console.log('error  = ', error);
              });
          }
```