# Angular Portal cdkPortal directive throw Expression Changed error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material Portal to move element in another place.

I use `cdkPortal` and `cdkPortalOutlet`.

I don't understand why angular throw expression changed in this super simple example

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkPortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild(CdkPortal, { static: false }) portal: CdkPortal
}
```

Check code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6sb21

open console to see error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'portal: undefined'. Current value: 'portal: [object Object]'
```

Comment: You should include the code snippet and console error here and be more precise about what part you don't understand

Comment: ERROR

Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'portal: undefined'. Current value: 'portal: [object Object]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the same object to the `cdkPortalOutlet`. You actually need another `ng-template` with its `ViewChild`

```
<ng-template #templatePortalContent>Hello, this is a template portal</ng-template>
```

and in the ts file:

```
// This is the reference for the ng-template that we added
@ViewChild("templatePortalContent", { static: false }) templatePortalContent: TemplateRef<any>;
// This is the variable that will hold the new template
templatePortal;

constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.templatePortal = new TemplatePortal(
    this.templatePortalContent,
    this._viewContainerRef
  );
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

This is for the TemplatePortal.

If you need a ComponentPortal, it means if you have already a component, then you will need to create the portal and assign it in the `cdkPortalOutlet` instead of `templatePortal` variable.

```
this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(ComponentPortalExample);
```

and

```
<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="componentPortal"></ng-template>
```

You can check [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) for more info:

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzr1lx).

Comment: In your demo you have the same problem, the same error in console. 'Expression Changed'

Comment: You can check the answer + demo now. You need to add the `cdr.detectChanges()` to manually trigger change detection. You can found more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243106/5613720