# Native Element is not defined in angular 8

Tags: angular, viewchild

**Framework: Angular 8**

Might I am missing up some thing, I need to get the `width` of element and set the `width` of child element divide by `5`.

My First attempt to get the value from `@ViewChild`, but getting error.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.

**code.ts**

```
@ViewChild("qrywrapper", { static: false }) qrywrapper: ElementRef;
qrycontainerWidth;
constructor() {}
ngOnInit() {
    /* Query Bar */
    this.qrycontainerWidth = this.qrywrapper.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    console.log(this.qrycontainerWidth, "container width");
    /* Query Bar end */
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="mx-3 flex-grow-1" #qrywrapper>
  <span [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px' : qryWidth }"></span>
</div>
```

**2nd Attempt through String interpol**

```
<div class="mx-3 flex-grow-1" #qrywrapper>
  <span [ngStyle]="{ 'width.%' : (qrywrapper.offsetWidth/5)-25 }"></span>
</div>
```

*(Width is divide with 5 and due to margin I subtract 25)*

In 2nd attempt, I got what I need, but getting this Error.

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'width.%: 218.8'. Current value:
>   'width.%: 218.2'.

Can some buddy tell me what I am getting `Native Element` error in first attempt and how to fix 2nd attempt code, so there will be no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only have access to it in `ngAfterViewInit` that gets called once the view for the component is initialized.

Try accessing the `nativeElement` in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook method:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    /* Query Bar */
    this.qrycontainerWidth = this.qrywrapper.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    console.log(this.qrycontainerWidth, "container width");
    /* Query Bar end */
}
```

Comment: great thanks :), can you tell me solve error in 2nd attempt?

Comment: Give **[this answer a try to fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243106/2622292)** and if you want to know more about the reason for it, please check **[this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/)** out