# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an Angular 10 application, I am trying to remove the navside component from the login component, so I created a service on the nave side component contains this code :

```js
visible: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.visible = true;

  }
  show() {
    this.visible = true;

  }
  hide() {
    this.visible = false;
  }
  toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
  doSomethingElseUseful() { }
```

and inside the naveside component i put :

```js
export class NavsideComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(public sr: ServService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
```

and the Html component :

```html
<div *ngIf="sr.visible">
    <mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" class="app-sidenav" opened>
            <mat-toolbar class="co">
                <span class="toolbar-filler"></span>

.
.
.
.
.
. </div>
```

but this error was displayed :

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.
```

**EDIT 1**

Login.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServService } from '../../navside/serv.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private sr :ServService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sr.hide();
    this.sr.doSomethingElseUseful();
  }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

Stackblitz putting together the snippets above, where the warning can be seen:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbkytu?file=src/app/login/login.component.ts

Comment: are you calling sr.show() anywhere?

Comment: im calling sr.hide() at login component

Comment: can you edit your post and include the login component.ts code?

Comment: Done , i have add it

Comment: Feels like a `this.cdr.detectChanges();` on `ngOnInit()` may solve the problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked

Comment: it doesn't enough

Answer (score 2):

I have edited your post to include a Stackblitz with a minimal reproducible example of the reported error. I suggest that in your next posts you **include a minimal reproducible example**, hence it´s more likelly you will have an answer.

**About ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError warning**

This post has usefull informations about this warning: [Expression ___ has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

In your specific case, the warning `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is shown because the value of `sr.visible` is changed twice during the initialization process:

- once during the service `SerService` creation and
- again in `loginComponent.ngOnInit()` when you call `sr.hide()`;

In the same round of change detection a value that is binded in the view (`sr.visible` is binded in `<div *ngIf="sr.visible">`) is not supposed to change values more than once, that's the reason of the warning.

**Solving your problem calling cdr.changeDetection() in the right component**

You can solve the problem calling `cdr.detectChanges()` in order to fire a second round of change detections. But for that to work, you need to call it in the component that has **the affected binding**.

Calling cdr.detectChanges() on **LoginComponent** has **no effect**, since the binding of `<div *ngIf="sr.visible">` is not in that component. You should call cdr.detectChanges() in the parent component where the binding is.

That said, the following use of cdr.detectChanges() in LoginComponent **will NOT solve the problem**:

```js
    export class LoginComponent {
      constructor(private sr: ServService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.sr.hide();
        this.sr.doSomethingElseUseful();
    
        //code bellow will NOT SOLVE the problem:
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    }
```

What will solve the problem is invoking cdr.detectChanges() on the component that has the binding `<div *ngIf="sr.visible">`.

In my working stackblitz (at the end of this answer), that component is AppComponent:

`app.component.html`:

```html
    <div *ngIf="sr.visible">
        Toolbar here
        <!-- your mat-side-nav and mat-toolbar here -->
    </div>
    <app-login></app-login>
```

So, the `cdr.detectChanges()` is called in the `ngOnInit()` of `app.component.ts`:

```js
    export class AppComponent {
      constructor(public sr: ServService, 
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    }
```

**Working version - stackblitz**

The working version calling detectChanges in the right component is available in the following Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nbb7bz?file=src/app/app.component.ts