# I'm using angular 10 with material, I got this error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, ngfor

this is angular html code, I think that the problem is caused by input component(app-product) that called into my view[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDGOM.png)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is only thrown in development mode, you won't see it in production.
It occurs when your input value changes before the Angular change detection lifecycle completes.

Although it doesn't have any side-effects as far as I know, you might want to change your child components (app-product in this particular example) [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) to OnPush, which will force Angular to only check for changes when one of your inputs value change.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried both methods and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating values of angular change listening variable inside **ngAfterViewInit()**,
If there, move that code to **ngOnInit()** or use **setTimeout** inside **ngAfterViewInit**

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried both methods and it works perfectly.