# NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a problem with this one.

I have a create a timeline to display schedule when vessels are supposed to dock on different terminals. it looks like that:

```
<ul class="vessels-schedule">
  <li *ngFor="let terminal of terminals" class="mt-3">
    <div class="terminal-schedule" #terminalSchedule #test>
      <div class="terminal-information" #terminalInformation>
        <h3 class="terminal-name">{{terminal.name}}</h3>          
      </div>
      <div *ngFor="let date of dates" class="vessel-date" #vesselDate></div>
      <div class="vessels">
        <div *ngFor="let vessel of terminal.vessels; let index = index"
            class="vessel" 
            [style.left.px]="getVesselPosition(vessel.estimateTimeArrival)"
            tabindex="0" #vessel>
        ...
```

It renders a row by terminal + a grid for each day `*ngFor="let date of dates"` and all vessels for this terminal positioned at the right date/time.

I have also a couples of `ViewChild` to dynamically calculate position:

```
@ViewChildren('terminalSchedule') terminalSchedule: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChild('terminalInformation') terminalInformation: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('vesselDate') vesselDate: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('vessel') vessel: ElementRef;

...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.terminalSchedule.changes.subscribe(item => {
    if (this.terminalSchedule.length) {
      this.terminalScheduleOffsetWidth = this.terminalSchedule.first.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
      this.terminalInformationOffsetWidth = this.terminalInformation.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
      this.vesselDateOffsetWidth = this.vesselDate.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
      this.vesselOffsetWidth = this.vessel !== undefined ? this.vessel.nativeElement.offsetWidth : 0;
      ...
```

And a function to set the position that returns a pixel value.

I don't know if it's because I don't initialize it at the right place, but when I bind data I have this in the console (it works though!):

```
NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'left': '0'. Current value: '301.5416666666667'.
```

I initialize the terminal list right in OnChanges():

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
  ...
  this.getTerminal();
}
```

Also, in the complementary question, I try to figure the best approach for resizing. Right now, I change a boolean property on resize to force re-render, I don't know if it's a good idea...

Comment: have you tried moving the logic to ngAfterContentInit ? https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Comment: I moved the content in ngAfterContentChecked with detectChanges() and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) with the method `detectChanges()` in your ngAfterViewInit().

```
constructor (private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { ... }

...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.cd.detectChanges();
   ... the rest of your method
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked

if I call detectChanges() in ngAfterContentChecked, it fix my problem.