# angular : changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
core.js:6162 ERROR Error: NG0100:
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
Previous value: 'null'. Current value: '{
```

I was trying to access the `{{dispositionDetails?.metricsData | json}}` it shows the object but it giving me the error mentioned above

how do we solve this one ? the `dispositionDetails` is from the tag `#dispositionDetails` as you can see on the code below. Any idea that might help?

#ts code

```
export class DealDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('pmrDetails') pmrDetails: any;
  @ViewChild('dispositionDetails') dispositionDetails: any;
```

#html code

```
<div class="page-content-details" *ngIf="urlData">
  <div class="page-content-details-left">
    <div>  
      <app-deal-pmr #pmrDetails
        *ngIf="urlData.dealType === 'Portfolio Management Restructure'"
        (gotoManageDealsEvent)="goBack()"
        (setIsInEditMode)="setIsInEditMode($event)"
        [dealData]="dealDetails"
        [transactionData]="urlData.transaction"
        [leaseDetails]="leaseDetails">
      </app-deal-pmr>    
      <app-deal-idle-disposition #dispositionDetails
        *ngIf="urlData.dealType === 'Idle Disposition'"
        (gotoManageDealsEvent)="goBack()"
        (setIsInEditMode)="setIsInEditMode($event)"
        [dealData]="dealDetails"
        [transactionData]="urlData.transaction"
        [leaseDetails]="leaseDetails">
      </app-deal-idle-disposition>
      <app-deal-partnership
        *ngIf="urlData.dealType === 'Partnership'"
        (gotoManageDealsEvent)="goBack()"
        [dealData]="dealDetails"
        [transactionData]="urlData.transaction"
        [leaseDetails]="leaseDetails">
      </app-deal-partnership>      
    </div>
    <app-page-section-cards [header]="pageSectionsOptions.checkList">
            <div sectionContent>        
      </div>
    </app-page-section-cards>


    {{dispositionDetails?.metricsData | json}}

    <app-page-section-cards [header]="pageSectionsOptions.metrics">
            <div sectionContent>             
        <app-deal-metrics 
          *ngIf="!isInEditMode"                
          [isInEditMode]="isInEditMode" 
          [dealData]="dealDetails"          
          [dealType]="urlData.dealType">
        </app-deal-metrics>   
        <app-deal-metrics    
          *ngIf="isInEditMode"       
          [isInEditMode]="isInEditMode" 
          [editData]="pmrDetails?.metricsData || dispositionDetails?.metricsData"
          [dealType]="urlData.dealType">
        </app-deal-metrics>             
      </div>
    </app-page-section-cards>   
  </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the full TS code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expression \_\_\_ has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with angular lifecycle hooks. See https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks
This error is thrown only in dev, as far as I've read.

Try setting a default value of pmrDetails ,dispositionDetails from inside ngOnInit / constructor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).