# for a pop-up i am panel getting error can anyone resolve this please angular version 1

Tags: angular, angular-material

Error:  ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'dialog'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?

Comment: i think requires your code of block to understand proper problem. may be below mention answer help you.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.