# What is the exact meaning of "Initializing component" and "displaying the data-bound properties" in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Angular doc says for `ngOnInit` ;

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.

But what does *exactly* **initializing**  mean ?

Because When I create a component and debug it, component doesn't display data-bound  properties
to *DOM* until `ngAfterViewInit` is called. But standart HTML elements are being rendered to the *DOM* when `ngOnInit` is called. Please check the following;

Component HTML

```
<h1 class="parent-normal"> I'M TRYING TO MAKE SENSE OF ANGULAR</h1> --> Being rendered when ngOninit is called

<div class="parent-data-bound">{{parentDataBound}}</div> -->Not being rendered until ngAfterViewInit is called

<app-child></app-child> --> Same as parent component. Standart HTML elements of child are being rendered when parent's ngOnInit component rendered. But data bound properties are not being rendered until
parent's ngAfterViewInit is rendered
```

So is the expression wrong what   [angular doc](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hooks-purpose-timing) says ? Because when  `ngOnInit` is called, data-bound
properties are **not** being rendered.

Comment: What you mean by "debugging"? I also debug, just 2 days ago and the own data of the component display right after constructor runs, after that, onInit run. I put breakpoint to the RenderView/UpdateView and trace down the code, each time I hit F9, I see one text appear on screen - this what I called "debug". You can read my answer and the link I attached to get more info about the lifecycle hook: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556232/4960765

Comment: I added breakpoints to all lifecycle hooks to see if DOM is being rendered. In ngOnInit hook, data-bound properties was not still rendered until ngAfterViewInit. Is that wrong way to debug ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it right or wrong as it depends on your data, the way you setup your component. As in my previous answer, every time I hit F9 (after set a breakpoint in TemplViewFn), it shows me each binding on screen, 1 F9 = 1 binding, so I know when and what exactly is rendering. At the same time, I add a console.log in each lifecycle hook, if after hitting F9, and see a console.log, I know they run together. But in my case, onInit always run after first binding.

Comment: So if you're sure your breakpoint always hit After onInit/lifecycle hook then you can share the stackblitz link here. We could debug together.

Comment: I don't know how to use deeply chrome debugger but I'm setting breakpoints to console.log statements like this ; https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tngipt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I checked and indeed the onInit run before data bound. Need to debug further, I will notify you later, it's 4 AM here

Comment: Alright, so the key word here is `data-bound properties`, that is the @input of the component, `name` in your example is the own data, not data-bound. Data-bound won't available in constructor so onInit is where we get it.

Comment: and yes, `name` or own properties is only available when the View/Component is checked, `AfterViewInit` is where Change Detection finished checking the own properties aka rendering own properties on screen. ContentInit is content projection, just to add more info.