# Update views after YouTube iFrame events in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, youtube

I'm trying to use [YouTube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) in angular2 but I run into a problem.

```
let onStateChange = (state) => {
    if (state.data === window['YT'].PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        console.log("window['YT'].PlayerState.PLAYING");
        this.isPlaying = true;
    }
    if (state.data === window['YT'].PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        console.log("window['YT'].PlayerState.PAUSED");
        this.isPlaying = false;
    }
};
```

and then

```
this.player = new window['YT'].Player("video-player", {events: { onStateChange } });
```

Callbacks handling the player events are executed but views don't get updated.

Here is the view:

```
<button class="control" (click)="play()" *ngIf="!isPlaying">Play</button>
<button class="control" (click)="pause()" *ngIf="isPlaying">Pause</button>
```

When I click on "Play", the video plays but the "Pause" button doesn't show up (the "Play" button doesn't disappear either).

When I click once again on the - not hidden - "Play" button, the video keeps playing and the "Play" button is replaced by "Pause". So it works the second time.

I googled it already but didn't find a solution:

- [angular 2.0 equivalent to $scope.$apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174146/angular-2-0-equivalent-to-scope-apply)
- [Angular 2 - Substitute for $scope.$apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734646/angular-2-substitute-for-scope-apply)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.

Import NgZone

```
import { ..., NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

Add NgZone as a property

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
```

And then

```
let onStateChange = (state) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => { // This was the trick
        if (state.data === window['YT'].PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            this.isPlaying = true;
        }
        if (state.data === window['YT'].PlayerState.PAUSED) {
            this.isPlaying = false;
        }
    });
};

this.player = new window['YT'].Player("video-player", { events: { onStateChange } });
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the whole code? I'm struggling to get the iframe api with angular 2 running.